# How can I find if this is the first event of that sensor? If yes assign it 0 otherwise increment the last number

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to assign an id based on the timestamp, i.e. if this is the first event assign 0 to that sensor's data, otherwise increment the last value for that id

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZdzd.png)

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lz0M.png)

Comment: any bit of code or something more you can share...this is kind of vague

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to ask a question here: [mcve]

Comment: Added input and output images in question. Please check